# Create a data flow diagram

Tags: processmodel

Prospective employees may apply at any time by filling out an application
which is kept on file by Projects, Inc. When a new job opens, engineering
managers notify the personnel manager who creates a new file that describes
the job and lists the characteristics necessary to be eligible for the job. The
personnel manager compares the qualifications of the available pool of
applicants with the characteristics of an open job, then schedules interviews
between the manager in charge of the open position and the three best
candidates from the pool.
After receiving evaluations on each interview from the manager, the
personnel manager makes the hiring decision based upon the evaluations and
applications of the candidates and the characteristics of the job, and then
notifies the applicant and the manager by phone. Applications of rejected
applicants are retained for one year, after which time the application is
purged. Currently, a clerk goes through the files each month to purge
applications over one year old. When hired, a new engineer completes a
nondisclosure agreement, which is filed with other information about the
employee

I tried chat-gpt and I was expecting a nice, detailed data flow diagram.